# How can I get if a crm dynamics 2011 update plugin was triggered by an activate/deactivate/merge action?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I build a plugin that runs in account update message that makes some validation not to duplicate the record. But if I try to disable that account or merge with another one it triggers the plugin.

How can I tell if the plugin was triggered by an activate/deactivate/merge action, or event mode like the one in CRM Dynamics 2011 [Save Event Arguments Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509060.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Pete Oakey's answer, you can actually tell your plugin to fire only when certain fields are changed at the *registration* phase, in addition to testing this in actual code @ runtime, by changing the "Filtering Attributes" of the plugin step. So unless your validation logic specifically needs the `StateCode`/`StatusCode` attributes to correctly process, you can filter those two attributes out, or just include the attributes your validation logic needs.

[image: Plugin Steps]

<strike>Original answer:</strike>

I believe you can reference the [`IExecutionContext.Depth Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iexecutioncontext.depth.aspx) of the `IPluginExecutionContext` object.

> Every time a running plug-in or Workflow issues a message request to
>   the Web services that triggers another plug-in or Workflow to execute,
>   the Depth property of the execution context is increased. If the depth
>   property increments to its maximum value within the configured time
>   limit, the platform considers this behavior an infinite loop and
>   further plug-in or Workflow execution is aborted. The maximum depth
>   (8) and time limit (one hour) are configurable by the Microsoft
>   Dynamics CRM administrator.

So you can use an if statement to check if `Depth > 1`.

Comment: I don't think his plugin is being called by a running plug-in or Workflow, it's being triggered by disabling the account through the GUI.

Comment: That's OK for activating and deactivating. But it will work for merge too?

Comment: When a merge happens, the contact status becomes "Inactive", but additionally, a `bool?` field called `Merge` is set to `true` and an `EntityReference` field called `MasterId` is set to the the master contact record. You'll want to ignore those as well.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to compare the before and after values of what's changed on the account entity in the plugin.  For example if you have only have `active` (if that's the right property name) in the values - you can look at the after value to see what's happened.

Another way would be to add a specific plugin for these messages and set some property/flag which you can check in the update plugin.  Obviously this would have to run before the update plugin.